# Information about transactional SMS

Tags: sms

*this is not a coding query, rather a how stuff works question *

I am working on a project for which I will 'receive' a huge number(say 1000/day or more) of transactional SMS (transactional SMS means those that have OTP etc, ones that are sent because I asked for it, unlike promotional SMS which comes unasked!). I want to receive them on my android mobile itself. Please answer these if you know:

1.If I keep deleting the SMSes and never let the memory get full, then, can I receive any number of those SMSes per day? By the way, what is the max number of messages that can be stored at once in a mobile inbox?

2.what if the queue has become of say 1000 pending SMS, what will happen, will senders server get terminate the queue/get hanged or send them one by one? I read such queued SMSes will be sent in bunches, like 10 at a time, then an interval, then next 10 and a longer interval and so on; if so, how long is that interval then?

3.Lastly, what about the transactional messages that are failed to be received? Will the sms server resend it at some later time? Or it's gone!

Answer as much as you can, these are very bad ques I know! Thanks for your time! :)

Comment: Did you try to find information yourself? And please edit your question - 2 and 3 are not Android specifica dn hove nothing to do with android.

Comment: i have had huge performance problems with stock sms app (the way how database is read) until i found a (payed) sms app which can handle 100.000 sms smooth

Answer (score 2):

I mentioned by @Άνδρας the questions 2 and 3 are not related to Android.

For the first question, I suggest two methods:

- Android App:

you can use an Android App that use [Alarm Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example) which will be executed once a day or every hour to clean up the SMS database using [Content Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics).

- ADB solutions:

```
content delete --uri content://sms --where "date>EPOCH_TIME"
```

where: EPOCH_TIME is 13 digit epoch time (milliseconds)

The command will delete all messages received after EPOCH_TIME